# Why globalize-compiler needs different globalize includes (npm vs. NuGet)?

Tags: globalize, jquery-globalize

After a lot of trying I got the globalize-compiler running and thus also got a js file with the **bundled CLDR** data (named **cldr_en.js**). In order to use it I have to do also the following includes:

```
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/message.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/number.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/plural.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/date.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/currency.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/relative-time.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/unit.js"></script>
<script src="cldr_en.js"></script>
```

These files come as dependencies to the **globalize-compiler** via **npm**.
The problem is that in my project I am using the NuGet **globalize** package. And if I try:

```
<script src="js/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize/message.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize/plural.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize/unit.js"></script>
<script src="cldr_en.js"></script>
```

I got js errors and the **globalize** does not work at all.
Could someone tell what is the difference in the globalize packages (npm and NuGet -> globalize vs. globalize-runtime) and if it is possible to work only with the **NuGet** package in the production.

I would like to setup a build where I use the **globalize-compiler** to get the **bundled CLDR** data and after that I want to delete the whole folder and dependencies of the **globalize-compiler** and only use the produced bundled **CLDR** files together with the **globalize** from the **NuGet**.

Comment: I'm not a NuGet user, but you can find globalize-runtime modules in here https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/tree/1.3.0/dist. Can you use npm instead?

Comment: Yes it is NuGet issue. I've already notified the owners of the NuGet jquery-globalize package to include the globalize-runtime modules with the standard NuGet jquery-globalize package.
Of course I could use the npm (this is what I'm doing now - and it was not easy and fast to find out!), but NuGet is standard in the VisualStudio world and one would not like to get the half of the packages from here and the other half from there - and it is not easy to remember that if you install the library from one source it will work and from the other it won't ... - this just needs a fix.

Comment: Could you please explain the internals of jquery globalize - specially why one needs globalize.js and then globalize-runtime.js - why there is no a single version? - this would be a good addition to the readme.md or the wiki page for the jquery-globalize project on the github site.

Comment: Basically, globalize-runtime is smaller than globalize and it should be used along with precompiled formatters and parsers. Differently from the regular globalize lib, globalize-runtime can't create new formatters and parsers. I am open to merge PRs clarifying that in the docs. Thanks for your help and question

Answer (score 1):

After some trying I've notice that **globalize-runtime.js** is part of the **globalize** package, but it does not get installed in VisualStudio through the **NuGet** wizard. So if one copies it there manually it works exactly as with the npm package (one should copy also the globalize-runtime folder containing files with the same names as in globalize, but they are not the same).

---

Edited 2018-01-15
The owners of the NuGet jquery-globalize package were notified to include the globalize-runtime files to the package.